# RSpec custom matchers in Cucumber to DRY implementation-dependent tests, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, integration-testing, bdd

I'm reading the new version of "Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl and, since I'm pretty fond in BDD with Cucumber, I found myself concerned about what the author points out here:   http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec:rspec_custom_matchers

In few words the main hassle with Cucumber is that it's impossible to DRY implementation-dependent tests like this:

```
Then /^he should see an error message$/ do
  page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')
end
```

writing RSpec custom matchers like this:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
  match do |page|
    page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
  end
end
```

Because such a custom matcher must be put in spec/support/utilities.rb and can be called from RSpec integration tests but not from Cucumber step definitions.

Are you positive / what you think about it?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking - do you want to share the `have_error_message` matcher between your Cucumber steps and your RSpec specs?  Or are you trying to reduce the duplication inside your Cucumber test suite?

Comment: The first purpose is to reduce duplication inside the Cucumber test suite aggregating implementation-dependent methods, but if it were possible to achieve this goal also reusing Rspec matchers, such as "have_error_message", it would be even DRYer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put implementation-dependent or reusable methods, locators to Cucumber World.

Example for your scenario:

```
# step_definitions/general_steps.rb
Then /^he should see an error message "(.+)"$/ do |text|
  within(error_message) do
    page.should have_content(text)
  end
end

# support/general_helpers.rb
module GeneralHelpers
  def error_message
    page.first('div.alert.alert-error')
  end
end

World(GeneralHelpers)
```

Here are some articles that refer to this approach:

- [It’s time to clean up your mess: refactoring Cucumber step definitions](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/7/its-time-to-clean-up-your-mess-refactoring-cucumber-step-definitions)
- [Using Cucumber World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World)

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly create RSpec matchers and use them in your Cucumber steps - I do this fairly frequently.  I just place them in `features/support/matchers` and they are instantly available to use in my step definitions.

If you wanted to share them with your RSpec tests as well, you may want to extract them to a separate `shared_test` type location, and then you could `require` that folder in both your Cucumber env.rb file, and your RSpec spec_helper.rb file, then they would be available in both test frameworks.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of that solution defining Cucumber's `World` method for RSpec, but this one is much simpler and cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: To make this work I had to add `require 'rspec/matchers'` at the beginning of the `features/support/matchers` file.

Answer (score 0):

An example of Jon M's answer, of how you can use RSpec custom matchers in Cucumber:

```
# spec/support/matchers/http.rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :return_http_success do
  match do |actual|
    actual >= 200 && actual <= 299
  end
end

# features/support/matchers.rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/matchers/*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
```